# jQuery selectors:  $('#ID1, #ID2, #ID3') vs $('1X CLASS')  which is faster?

Tags: jquery

Looking into selector performance between $('#ID1, #ID2, #ID3') vs $('1X CLASS'). Which is faster?

Comment: i haven't done any research but i'm guessing the former. i imagine all comma separated selectors will just be divided into separate selectors and joined into one result set. given that, it'll just be a set of `getElementById` s, which is pretty much the quickest way to access a DOM node in javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `.class` is working faster for this case. jQuery might not be going the `getElementById` route. Chrome and Safari are probably being optimizing with `getElementsByClassName`.

Tests @ http://jsfiddle.net/mGqyH/4/

Chrome

[Chrome http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5021/chromew.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5021/chromew.png)

---

Safari

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5021/chromew.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5021/chromew.png)

---

Firefox

[Firefox performance http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1123/firefoxg.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1123/firefoxg.png)

---

Document used (modified)

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html
```

combined IDs selector

```
$("#Events, #table-of-contents, #Events-overview, #Events-flow-capture, #Events-EventTarget, #Events-EventListener")
```

disjoint IDs selector

```
$("#Events").add("#table-of-contents").add("#Events-overview").add("#Events-flow-capture").add("#Events-EventTarget").add("#Events-EventListener");
```

class selector

```
$(".selectMe")
```

Comment: I don't have access to IE. but made the answer a CW. Feel free to add results foe IE here.

Comment: Interesting how firefox's time for disjoint ID's is so large.

Comment: Got results similar to Firefox on Opera too. The query goes through `jQuery(document).find("#someID")` for each `add` call, which in turn uses the new Sizzle engine. But since it works fast on Webkit browsers, it might have to do with tweaks and optimizations by the browser itself.

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead, if you want performance:

```
$("#id1").add("#id2").add("#id3")
```

There's less string parsing to do here. That should be faster than selecting by class name, *unless* the browser has a native implementation (some do).

Answer (score 3):

In general, searching for id's is done by getElementbyId, which is the fastest possible way to select a DOM element. If available, getElementByClass is used to grab a node by class name.

Again, getElementById is the fastest way. Performing getElementById three times against one getElementByClass needs some benchmarking to find out the speed difference.

But if the browser does not support getElementByClass, it's even more slow.

Answer (score 2):

Updated http://jsfiddle.net/uD7Qz/1/ with .add method.

.add method is almost as fast as $(.class), on Chrome. On FireFox it's 4x slower then $("#1, #2, #4").

Atleast those were my results.

Comment: Interesting results. I got the same for Chrome and Safari (`.add` and `.class` both very close), but in Firefox (`.add` took 5x the time whereas `#a, #b, #c` and `.class` were both very close.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a guess, I'd say selecting by ID is faster, since `document.getElementByID()` is a built-in function to javascript, while 'getElementByClass()' is something that various custom functions have been built to solve. Ideally too, looking for `$('div#id')` is going to be faster because it's more specific and allows the search loop to cut out certain paths that have no chance of coming back positive.

Comment: have you done any research to back the `div#id` claim? i don't see that there's any native implementation to match that in a way that the specificity of the selector could be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors work on same principle as that of CSS selectors(generalized statement not an exact fact).And in CSS , id selector are more faster when compared to that of class selector.So $("#myDiv") is more faster than #(".myDivClass").